# How to use dartdoc to generate the documentation for flutter like docs.flutter.io?

Tags: dart, flutter

I found the command of **dartdoc**, when I run it, I get the api documantation for *Dart*. How can I generate the documantation for flutter just like docs.flutter.io?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Run from the project root directory the command line command

**new**

```
dart doc
```

**old**

```
pub global activate dartdoc
dartdoc
```

See also https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dartdoc

By default docs are only generate for the public API in `lib/`.
Code in `lib/src/` is considered private if not exported from files in `lib/`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works, I generated docs of flutter successfully

Comment: @Creatint glad to hear. If this solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer to mark it as answered using the checkmark below the up/down-vote button. Thanks.

Comment: dartdoc attempts to parse all the sources of flutter, along with my project files. Is that normal?

Comment: 'pub' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You are missing a path setting to your Dart install direcory's `bin` subdirectory. If you use linux only the `dart` executable is put into `/usr/bin`, the other tools are in `/usr/lib/dart/bin` and you need to add a path to that directory yourself. I don't know about Windows, but probably similar with another install directory.

Comment: @SathishGadde sorry, I missed that this is Flutter-specific. If you do not have Dart SDK installed, then use `flutter pub global activate dartoc` instead. It just forwards to `pub` with some additional settings.

Comment: Thanks to all, am added dart sdk and now am able to generate doc.

Comment: Doc  generated successfully. But,methods inside of widget not visible. Only static const variable comments visible in doc output. None of the user defined methods visible in final doc.

Comment: Splash screen widget have 1 static const and one method. But in generated doc am seen only static const variable , method not visible in final doc. Please let me know if need any configuration or change.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the method public? (default if the name does not start with `_`). Otherwise I don't think I can help you. I didn't use `dartdoc` much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208642/discussion-between-sathish-gadde-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: https://dart.dev/tools/dart-doc The command is now `dart doc` with a space in between the words.